# Angular form with dynamic input values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, data-binding

I am having issues with angular not picking up the dynamic values from my inputs.

This is what I'm trying to do. When a user clicks on map, the angular populates the hidden form fields with lat/lon, and the user then submits the form, which ends up missing data on the controller.

Here is the relevant controller code :

```
$scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submit = function(addressform) {
      addressService.createAdddress($scope.formData).then(function(result) {
        $scope.addressResponse = result;
      }, function(err) {
          alert(err);
      });
    }

    $scope.userSelectedPoint = function () {
      $scope.lat = map.getLat();
      $scope.lon = map.getLon();
      $scope.address = map.getAddress();
    }
```

This is the relevant HTML :

```
<form id="address_form" name="addressform" ng-submit="submit(addressform)">

   <input "lattitude" name="lattitude" type="hidden" ng-model="formData.lattitude" value="{{lat}}">
   <input id="longitude" name="longitude"type="hidden" ng-model="formData.longitude" value="{{lon}}">

   <p>Selected Address: {{address}}</p>
</form>
```

Everything looks ok in the chrome inspector(random point on a map) :

[image]

However when I submit this form and print out a `$scope.formData` I get an empty object:

```
$scope.formData
Object {}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the `formData` in my controller empty, when obviously the value is set in the HTML as it can be seen from the screenshot I pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign the values to `ng-model` variable, not to the `value`

as

```
<input "lattitude" name="lattitude" type="hidden" ng-model="formData.lattitude" />
<input id="longitude" name="longitude"type="hidden" ng-model="formData.longitude" />
```

assign the value to `formData.lattitude`.

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.userSelectedPoint = function () {
  $scope.formData.lattitude = map.getLat();
  $scope.formData.longitude  = map.getLon();
  $scope.formData.address = map.getAddress();
}
```

in angular if you provide a value to a variable and u assign that variable to input using `ng-model` then the input is getting the value of variable, anf if we change input value variable value gets change.

so your assign the `lattitude` property of `formData` object to a input. that means if you change the `$scope.formData.lattitude` input value gets change.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can't use the value property. You have to initialize the **formData** object with longitude/lattitude. And therefore you also need any fake hidden field. You don't need this pattern in Angular.